# Negative time differences in Oracle with only one -

Tags: sql, oracle, time, difference

```
select 
    to_char(trunc(mod(-5400,3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' ||
    to_char(mod(-5400,60),'FM00')||':00'
FROM DUAL;
```

for -ve times...its displaying something like -32:-23:-23

I want it to display some thing like '-32:23:23'.

Tried extract function too...but no luck. Any input appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? it seems like you could use interval datatype instead of this - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00207

Answer (score 1):

How about just taking the abs() of the minutes / seconds?

```
SELECT To_char(Trunc(MOD(-5423, 3600) / 60), 'FM00') 
       || ':' 
       || To_char(Abs(MOD(-5423, 60)), 'FM00') 
       ||':00' 
FROM   dual;
```

Comment: Actually its working for time difference > 1 hour. But for the time difference < 1 hour it was showing as positive...I need some thing like, for -10 min, I want to display '-00:15:00'